# Adding table notes over the length of the page

Tags: tables, tablenotes

I have a very narrow table and having tables notes below that doesn't look good. I need to spread the notes over the width of the page. Im posting my current code herewith. Any help is much appreciated.

Chana

```
    \begin{table}[]
    \centering
    \caption{Percentage (\%) ghdghgh}
    \label{tab:si}%
    \begin{threeparttable}
    \begin{tabular}{|l|dd|}
        \cmidrule{1-3} 
        \multicolumn{3}{c}{(1)} \\
        \cmidrule{1-3}    \multicolumn{1}{r}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Small} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Big} \\
        \midrule
        \vspace{2mm}
        L  & 0.1952 & 0.2310 \\ 
        I & 0.6652 & 0.0807 \\
        \midrule
        IL   & 0.4699^{*} & -0.1503 \\ 
        t-stat & (1.8508) & -(0.5168) \\
        \midrule
        \multicolumn{3}{c}{} \\
        \cmidrule{1-3} 
        \multicolumn{3}{c}{(2)} \\
        \cmidrule{1-3}
        \multicolumn{1}{r}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{L}  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{I} \\        
        \midrule
        \vspace{2mm}
        Small & 0.2433 &  0.5535  \\ 
        Big   & 0.2428 &  0.1746 \\
        \midrule
        SMB   & 0.0005  &  0.3789^{**} \\
        t-stat & (0.0029) &  (2.2308) \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%
    \begin{tablenotes}
        \scriptsize 
        Note: aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa.    
    \end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}%
```

Comment: (i) firs make your code compilable, i.e.: extend table code to complete small document. (ii) for table note use dummy text from package `lipsum` or `blindterxt` etc. (iii) whay you like to have this long note as table note? the simple paragraph  below table can gives what you looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one way is put your long note in `minipage` below table:

[image]

in lack of information about your document, i wrote own from scratch. consequently i may significantly differ from yours:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs, threeparttable}
%\renewcommand{\tnote}[1]{\textsuperscript{\textbf{[#1]}}}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[11]
%
\begin{table}[htb]
\centering
\caption{Percentage (\%) ghdghgh}
\label{tab:si}%
\begin{threeparttable}
\begin{tabular}{ l
            *{2}{S[input-symbols = {(- )},
                  table-space-text-pre={(},
                  table-space-text-post ={**},
                  table-format=-1.4]}
                  }
    \toprule
    \multicolumn{3}{c}{(1)}         \\
    \midrule
                    &   {Small}         &   {Big}       \\
    \midrule
    L               &   0.1952          &   0.2310      \\
    I               &   0.6652          &   0.0807      \\
    \addlinespace
    IL              &   0.4699\tnote{*} &  -0.1503      \\
    t-stat          &  (1.8508)         & -(0.5168)     \\
    \midrule &                   &               \\
    \multicolumn{3}{c}{(2)}                             \\
    \midrule
                    &   {L}             &   {I}         \\
    \midrule
    Small           &   0.2433          &  0.5535       \\
    Big             & 0.2428            &  0.1746       \\
    \addlinespace
    SMB             & 0.0005            &  0.3789\tnote{**} \\
    t-stat          & (0.0029)          &  (2.2308) \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}%
\begin{tablenotes}[para, flushleft]\footnotesize
\item[*] some explanation
\item[**] some explanation
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}

\medskip
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}\footnotesize
    Note: \lipsum*[1]
\end{minipage}
\end{table}
%
\lipsum[11]
\end{document}
```

another solution, which cross my mind is split your table into two parts and write them in parallel:

[image]

to set split `tabular`s in parallel they had to be encapsulated into `\tabular` environment (otherwise `threeparttable` doesn't allow them to be parallel). with  `[referable]{threeparttablex}` is provided  (among others)  macro `\note` for `tablenotes`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}% <--- added
\usepackage{booktabs, threeparttable}
\usepackage[referable]{threeparttablex}% <--- added
\renewcommand{\tnote}[1]{\textsuperscript{\textbf{#1}}}% <--- added
\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[11]
%
\begin{table}[htb]
\centering
\begin{threeparttable}
    \caption{Percentage (\%) ghdghgh}% <--- moved here
    \label{tab:si}%
\begin{tabular}{@{} c @{}}% <--- added tabular
    \begin{tabular}{ l
            *{2}{S[input-symbols = {(- )},
                  table-space-text-pre={(},
                  table-space-text-post ={**},
                  table-format=-1.4]}
                  }% <--- first part of table
    \toprule
    \multicolumn{3}{c}{(1)}         \\
    \cmidrule(lr){1-3}
                    &   {Small}         &   {Big}       \\
    \midrule
    L               &   0.1952          &   0.2310      \\
    I               &   0.6652          &   0.0807      \\
    \addlinespace
    IL              &   0.4699\tnote{*} &  -0.1503      \\
    t-stat          &  (1.8508)         & -(0.5168)     \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%
    \begin{tabular}{ l
            *{2}{S[input-symbols = {(- )},
                  table-space-text-pre={(},
                  table-space-text-post ={**},
                  table-format=-1.4]}
                  }% <--- second part of table
    \toprule
    \multicolumn{3}{c}{(2)}                             \\
    \cmidrule(lr){1-3}
                    &   {L}             &   {I}         \\
    \midrule
    Small           &   0.2433          &  0.5535       \\
    Big             & 0.2428            &  0.1746       \\
    \addlinespace
    SMB             & 0.0005            &  0.3789\tnote{**} \\
    t-stat          & (0.0029)          &  (2.2308) \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{tabular}
\begin{tablenotes}[para, flushleft]\footnotesize
\item[*] some explanation
\item[**] some explanation

\note   \lipsum*[1]
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\lipsum[11]
\end{document}
```